# Store exception body in variable

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Is there a way to execute a `try` statement and return the error body as a variable?

i.e.

```
var = ''
try:
    error generating code
except:
    var = exception_body
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, use the `as` syntax of `except`:

```
try:
    raise Exception("hello world")
except Exception as x:
    print(x)
```

In earlier versions of Python, this would be written `except Exception, x:` which you may see from time to time.